# Error adding flyway-sbt plugin for Scala 2.12 (Play Framework)

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, flyway, sbt-plugin

**TLDR:** Are there any publically available jars for `flyway-sbt` for Scala `2.12` and SBT `1.0`?

---

Has anyone else had issues with dependency resolution for `flyway-sbt` when using Scala `2.12`? Looking at the URLs below, they indeed **do not exist**.

```
[warn]  module not found: org.flywaydb#flyway-sbt;4.0
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.flywaydb/flyway-sbt/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0//4.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.flywaydb/flyway-sbt/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0//4.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/adu/.ivy2/local/org.flywaydb/flyway-sbt/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0//4.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/flywaydb/flyway-sbt_2.12_1.0/4.0/flyway-sbt-4.0.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/adu/.sbt/preloaded/org.flywaydb/flyway-sbt/4.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/adu/.sbt/preloaded/org/flywaydb/flyway-sbt_2.12_1.0/4.0/flyway-sbt-4.0.pom
[warn] ==== Flyway: tried
[warn]   https://flywaydb.org/repo/org/flywaydb/flyway-sbt_2.12_1.0/4.0/flyway-sbt-4.0.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.flywaydb#flyway-sbt;4.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]    org.flywaydb:flyway-sbt:4.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]    org.flywaydb:flyway-sbt:4.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/Users/adu/workspace/seed-play/project/plugins.sbt#L42-43)
[warn]      +- default:seed-play-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.flywaydb#flyway-sbt;4.0: not found
```

These are the additions to my `plugins.sbt` file:

```
resolvers += "Flyway" at "https://flywaydb.org/repo"
addSbtPlugin("org.flywaydb" % "flyway-sbt" % "4.0")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out Flyway has yet to publish official artifacts for `flyway-sbt` compatible with `sbtVersion=1.x`.

After some digging, I found this [Github issue](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1741).
Which then lead to this new [Github repository](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-sbt).
The above is part of the Flyway github account, so it should be maintained.

Replacing the additions to my plugins.sbt file with the following worked:

```
resolvers += "Flyway" at "https://davidmweber.github.io/flyway-sbt.repo"
addSbtPlugin("org.flywaydb" % "flyway-sbt" % "4.2.0")
```